# interrupt and poll() or epoll()

Tags: linux, interrupt

We register an event using `poll()` or `epoll()`, then `poll_wait()` or `epoll_wait()` waits for an event. When I/O input pins generates an interrupt, ISR handler is invoked. How do we link the interrupt or ISR to `poll_wait()` or `epoll_wait()`?

What event we register for the interrupt?
Thanks

Comment: Can your ISR handler send a byte on a pipe, and have poll()/epoll() listen on the other end of that pipe and react when the byte is received?

Comment: @Jeremy, thanks. Of course yes, if that the only solution